# External USB optical drive gets recognized as SCSI, can't be mounted

Tags: usb-drive

I am trying to attach a USB DVD/RW optical drive at my Raspberry Pi 4, running Raspbian.

```
$uname -a
Linux ras4 4.19.93-v7l+ #1290 SMP Fri Jan 10 16:45:11 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The drive is fully working; I have tested it with Windows, and it ran on Bananian several years ago (as drive /dev/sr0).

When I attach it to my Raspberry, following entries will be added to syslog:

```
Apr 13 00:11:34 ras4 kernel: [6312011.699514] usb 1-1.2.4.2: new high-speed USB device number 79 using xhci_hcd
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 vhusbdarm[669]: Found High speed device [152e:1640] "HLDS Inc, SuperMulti RW   " at address 11242
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 kernel: [6312014.270562] usb 1-1.2.4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=152e, idProduct=1640, bcdDevice= 1.59
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 kernel: [6312014.270581] usb 1-1.2.4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 kernel: [6312014.270596] usb 1-1.2.4.2: Product: SuperMulti RW
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 kernel: [6312014.270608] usb 1-1.2.4.2: Manufacturer: HLDS Inc
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 kernel: [6312014.270621] usb 1-1.2.4.2: SerialNumber: 00101016400014AB5
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 kernel: [6312014.272784] usb-storage 1-1.2.4.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 kernel: [6312014.273308] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.2.4.2:1.0
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 79: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4.2"
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 79 was not an MTP device
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 79: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2.4/1-1.2.4.2"
Apr 13 00:11:36 ras4 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 79 was not an MTP device
Apr 13 00:11:37 ras4 kernel: [6312015.301669] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GE20NU10  EE06 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Apr 13 00:11:37 ras4 kernel: [6312015.302557] scsi 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
```

There is no device /dev/sr* or /dev/cdrom available. The syslog does not contain the line "Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0"

Trying to mount /dev/sg1 fails with message "Not a block device", and lsblk does not list it:

```
$lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0   256M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0 465,5G  0 part /
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29,7G  0 disk
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  29,7G  0 part /boot
```

What can I do? Is it possible that the kernel does not support this device?

Comment: can you show `udevadm info --query=all -n /dev/sg1 --attribute-walk `

Comment: @nobody Thank you for your reply. Here is the output of the command:  https://pastebin.com/68SjnB6T

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem.

For some reason, the kernel modul "sr_mod" could not be loaded.
Probably something was wrong with my kernel.

```
$ modprobe sr_mod.ko
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.93-v7l+/modules.dep                                                                                                             .bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module sr_mod not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.93-v7l+
```

The weird thing is that sr_mod.so is actually existing:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/4.19.97*/kernel/drivers/scsi/sr_mod.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28K Feb  3 13:50 /lib/modules/4.19.97+/kernel/drivers/scsi/sr_mod.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30K Feb  3 13:50 /lib/modules/4.19.97-v7+/kernel/drivers/scsi/sr_mod.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30K Feb  3 13:50 /lib/modules/4.19.97-v7l+/kernel/drivers/scsi/sr_mod.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37K Feb  3 13:50 /lib/modules/4.19.97-v8+/kernel/drivers/scsi/sr_mod.ko

$ uname -a
Linux ras4 4.19.93-v7l+ #1290 SMP Fri Jan 10 16:45:11 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The solution was to reinstall the kernel and reboot the system:

```
$ apt install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel
$ reboot
```

After the reboot, the modul sr_mod is automatically loaded, and /dev/sr0 will become available.